# Python Flask: How to wait for webhook to be executed?

Tags: python, flask, webhooks

I am working on a Python flask app, and the main method `start()` calls an external API (`third_party_api_wrapper()`). That external API has an associated webhook (`webhook()`) that receives the output of that external API call (note that the output that `webhook()` receives is actually different from the `response` returned in the `third_party_wrapper()`)

The main method `start()` needs the result of `webhook()`. How do I make `start()` wait for `webhook()` to be executed? And how do wo pass the returned value of `webhook()` back to `start()`?

Here's is a minimal code snippet to capture the scenario.

```
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    return "webhook method has executed"

# this method has a webhook that calls webhook() after this method has executed
def third_party_api_wrapper():
    url = 'https://api.thirdparty.com'
    response = requests.post(url)
    return response

# this is the main entry point
@app.route('/start', methods=['POST'])
def start():
    third_party_api_wrapper()
    # The rest of this code depends on the output of webhook(). 
    # How do we wait until webhook() is called, and how do we access the returned value?
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question really depends on how you plan on running your app in production. It's much simpler if we make the assumption that you only plan to have a single instance of your app running at once (as opposed to multiple behind a load balancer, for example), so I'll make that assumption first to give you a place to start, and comment on a more "production-ready" solution afterwards.

A big thing to keep in mind when writing a web application is that you have to understand how you want the outside world to interact with your app. Do you expect to have the `/start` endpoint called only once at the beginning of your app's lifetime, or is this a generic endpoint that may start any number of background processes that you want the caller of each to wait for? Or, do you want the behavior where any caller after the first one will wait for the same process to complete as the first one? I can't answer these questions for you, it depends on the use-case you're trying to implement. I'll give you a relatively simple solution that you should be able to modify to fulfill any of the ones I mentioned though.

This solution will use the [`Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event) class from the `threading` standard library module; I added some comments to clarify which parts you may have to change depending on the specifics of the API you're calling and stuff like that.

```py
import threading
import uuid
from typing import Any

import requests
from flask import Flask, Response, request


# The base URL for your app, if you're running it locally this should be fine
# however external providers can't communicate with your `localhost` so you'll
# need to change this for your app to work end-to-end.
BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000"

app = Flask(__name__)


class ThirdPartyProcessManager:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.events = {}
        self.values = {}

    def wait_for_request(self, request_id: str) -> None:
        event = threading.Event()
        actual_event = self.events.setdefault(request_id, event)
        if actual_event is not event:
            raise ValueError(f"Request {request_id} already exists.")
        event.wait()
        return self.values.pop(request_id)

    def finish_request(self, request_id: str, value: Any) -> None:
        event = self.events.pop(request_id, None)
        if event is None:
            raise ValueError(f"Request {request_id} does not exist.")
        self.values[request_id] = value
        event.set()


MANAGER = ThirdPartyProcessManager()


# This is assuming that you can specify the callback URL per-request, otherwise
# you may have to get the request ID from the body of the request or something
@app.route('/webhook/<request_id>', methods=['POST'])
def webhook(request_id: str) -> Response:
    MANAGER.finish_request(request_id, request.json)
    return "webhook method has executed"


# Somehow in here you need to create or generate a unique identifier for this
# request--this may come from the third-party provider, or you can generate one
# yourself. There are three main paths I see here:
# - If you can specify the callback/webhook URL in each call, you can just pass them
#   <base>/webhook/<request_id> and use that to identify which request is being
#   responded to in the webhook.
# - If the provider gives you a request ID, you can return it from this function
#   then retrieve it from the request body in the webhook route
# For now, I'll assume the first situation but you should be able to implement the second
# with minimal changes
def third_party_api_wrapper() -> str:
    request_id = uuid.uuid4().hex
    url = 'https://api.thirdparty.com'
    # Just an example, I don't know how the third party API you're working with works
    response = requests.post(
        url,
        json={"callback_url": f"{BASE_URL}/webhook/{request_id}"}
    )
    # NOTE: unrelated to the problem at hand, you should always check for errors
    # in HTTP responses. This method is an easy way provided by requests to raise
    # for non-success status codes.
    response.raise_for_status()
    return request_id


@app.route('/start', methods=['POST'])
def start() -> Response:
    request_id = third_party_api_wrapper()
    result = MANAGER.wait_for_request(request_id)
    return result
```

If you want to run the example fully locally to test it, do the following:

1. Comment out lines 62-71, which actually make the external API call
2. Add a print statement after line 77, so that you can get the ID of the "in flight" request. E.g. `print("Request ID", request_id)`
3. In one terminal, run the app by pasting the above code into an `app.py` file and running `flask run` in that directory.
4. In another terminal, start the process via:

```bash
curl -XPOST http://localhost:5000/start
```

5. Copy the request ID that will be logged in the first terminal that's running the server.
6. In a third terminal, complete the process by calling the webhook:

```bash
curl -XPOST http://localhost:5000/webhook/<your_request_id> -H Content-Type:application/json -d '{"foo":"bar"}'
```

You should see `{"foo":"bar"}` as the response in the second terminal that made the `/start` request.

I hope that's enough to help you get started w/ whatever problem you're trying to solve.

There are a couple of design-y comments I have based on the information provided as well:

- As I mentioned before, this will not work if you have more than one instance of the app running at once. This works by storing the state of in-flight requests in a global state inside your python process, so if you have more than one process, they won't all be working and modifying the same state. If you need to run more than one instance of your process, I would use a similar approach with some database backend to store the shared state (assuming your requests are pretty short-lived, Redis might be a good choice here, but once again it'll depend on exactly what you're trying to do).
- Even if you do only have one instance of the app running, flask is capable of being run in a variety of different server contexts--for example, the server might be using threads (the default), greenlets via `gevent` or a similar library, or multiple processes, or maybe some other approach entirely in order to handle multiple requests concurrently. If you're using an approach that creates multiple processes, you should be able to use the utilities provided by the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event) module to implement the same approach as I've given above.
- This approach probably will work just fine for something where the difference in time between the API call and the webhook response is small (on the order of a couple of seconds at most I'd say), but you should be wary of using this approach for something where the difference in time can be quite large. If the connection between the client and your server fails, they'll have to make another request and run the long-running process that your third party is completing for you again. Some proxies and load balancers may also have time out behavior that could terminate the request after a certain amount of time even if nothing goes wrong in the connection between your server and the client making a request to it. An alternative approach would be for your `/start` endpoint to return quickly and give the client a `request_id` that they could poll for updates. As an example, AWS Athena's API is structured like this--there is a `StartQueryExecution` method, and separate `GetQueryExecution` and `GetQueryResults` methods that the client makes requests to check the status of a query and retrieve the results respectively (there are also other methods like `StopQueryExecution` and `GetQueryRuntimeStatistics` available as well). You can check out the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html).

I know that's a lot of info, but I hope it helps. Happy to update the answer w/ more specific info if you'll provide some more details about your use-case.